# C# merge multiple arrays to one array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, merge, jagged-arrays

I get x-Amount of `Arrays` out of an `jagged array` looking like this:

```
string[] sArray1 = {"FB1" , "FB(1)" , "V1.0"};
string[] sArray2 = {"FB1" , "FB(1)" , "" , "V1.0"};
string[] sArray3 = {"FB2" , "FB(2)" , "V5.2"}
```

and I want to merge them into one `Array` when

```
sArray1[0] == sArray2[0] && sArray1[1] == sArray2[1]
```

the merged `Array` should look like this

```
string[] sArray12 = {"FB1" , "FB(1)" , "V1.0" , "V1.0"};
```

I already tried it with `Array.CopyTo()`; and `Enumerable.Union<>`.
The problem with `Enumerable.Union<>` was that when field 3 and 4 had the same value only field 3 would have been written in the `Array`. 
Is there a way so that both values get written? Or is there a better approach to my problem?

Comment: "V2.0" isn't in the first or second array. Where is it coming from?

Comment: edited it, it should have been "V1.0"

Comment: You want both "V1.0" to appear, but you don't want "FB1" to appear twice?

Comment: You wrote the condition `sArray[0] == sArray2[0]`, but where is the `sArray` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
if (sArray1[0] == sArray2[0] && sArray1[1] == sArray2[1])
{
   var sArray12 = sArray1.Concat(sArray2.Skip(2))
                         .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) //probably
                         .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: more like `sArray1.Concat(sArray2.Skip(3)).ToArray`

Comment: @Slai I guess that would be `Skip(2)` though, but yeah, fixed that

Comment: But what about concatenating many arrays? any simpler way than calling concat a bunch of times?